# vertical aligning images in table with \adjustbox only works when not every image is in an \adjustbox

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, adjustbox

I'm trying to center all images vertically and horizontally within a table cell.

Therefore I'm using the `adjustbox` packet. This is the code I use for my table:

```
 \begin{table}[b]
 \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }
     \hline                
      \adjustbox{valign=m}{
        \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{./images/buttons/Windows-Buttons.png}
      }
      & 
      \adjustbox{valign=m}{
        \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{./images/buttons/MacOSX-Buttons.png}
      }
      & 
      [...]
      & 
      \adjustbox{valign=m}{
        \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{./images/buttons/Android-Buttons.png}
      }

      \\[.8cm] 

     \hline
     Windows 7 & Mac OS X & Gnome & iOS & Android \\
 \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vspace{-.5cm}
\caption{Buttons verschiedener Betriebssysteme}
\end{table}
```

If I attach adjustbox to every `\includegraphics` I don't get the desired output: [image: http://i47.tinypic.com/apiu12.jpg]

If I remove only one `\adjustbox` (no matter which one), with following code:

```
%\adjustbox{valign=m}{
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{./images/buttons/MacOSX-Buttons.png}
%}
```

I get the desired result (well, some kind of ...): 
[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/11kxlk9.jpg]

I don't have to use `\adjustbox`. I just want the images to be vertically and horizontally centered.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Pleas always post complete, compilable but minimal examples, i.e. add a small preamble etc. Some general notes: Please add a `%` on lines ending on `{` to avoid getting a space here from the line break, i.e. write `\adjustbox{valign=m}{%`. Note that with the `export` option of `adjustbox` you can use `valign=m` directly as `\includegraphics` option. There is also a `\adjustimage` macro. The `center` environment should not be used inside `table`. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651)

Comment: Thank you for your advice about formatting a post and about how to use adjustbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not an issue with `adjustbox`. The first image is exactly what your code requests: All images vertically aligned plus 0.8cm whitespace at the bottom. Apparently you want also some whitespace on top, which is however not the job of `valign`. You may use the `margin` option of `adjustbox` here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{mwe}% for this example only

\begin{document}

\lipsum % example text

\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio,valign=m,margin=0cm .8cm]{example-image}
    & 
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio,valign=m,margin=0cm .8cm]{example-image-a}
    & 
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio,valign=m,margin=0cm .8cm]{example-image-b}
    & 
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio,valign=m,margin=0cm .8cm]{example-image-c}
    & 
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio,valign=m,margin=0cm .8cm]{example-image-1x1}
    \\
    \hline
    Windows 7 & Mac OS X & Gnome & iOS & Android \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Buttons verschiedener Betriebssysteme}
\end{table}

\lipsum % example text

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

However 0.8cm seems to be a little to large here.

Comment: Also note that the order in which the options to `includegraphics` are used is important---i.e., set your margins after the width and height and the `keepaspectratio`. I was too slow to figure that one out to post the answer before @martin-scharrer:-)

Comment: @ArTourter: The order-sensitivity is intentionally. You can e.g. first add a border and then resize if you want so.

Comment: I know that and it makes sense but I had not tweaked to it.  I did not see it mention explicitly in the docs so I thought I'd mention it here since I encountered it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand the usage of the `export` function of `adjustbox`. Your solution works great!

I have two more questions:
1) According to your post, the `\\[.8cm]` don't define the row height, they define whitespace at the bottom of a row? Because it was my intention to define the row height with this code.
2) Do I still need `\\[.8cm]` if I write `margin=.8cm .8cm`? Or does `margin=.8cm .8cm` set the right/left margin to `.8cm` and not the top/bottom?

Comment: @FlyingRocket `margin=.8cm .8cm` will set both "left/right" and "top/bottom"  to .8cm. if you only want the top/bottom margins set, you should use `margin=0pt .8cm`. And no you should not need the `\\[.8cm]` any more.

Comment: @ArTourter thanks a lot. This reminds me of the margin usage within CSS.

Comment: @FlyingRocket yes funnily I have been trying to find the equivalent of the CSS margin/padding in LaTeX for a while and thanks to your question, now I have!

Comment: @FlyingRocket: just check the description of `margin` in the `adjustbox` content. As said, `\\[.8cm]` will add additional vertical space after the row, not set the height.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thank you. How would one set the height of the row?